# Responsive table design for small devices - table {"display:block"}

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I got a good solution for my responsive table design with Chris Coyier [article](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) on using "display:block" on my table form.

```
/* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px){table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
    display: block; 
}}
```

I used min-width instead of max-width (in article) for my design, and now I have problems in setting "table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr" back again to the regular table view in higher resolutions "@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){}"

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: try change `min-width` to `max-width` and `0px` to `767px`

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have "min-width" on your @media query set to 0px. Essentially meaning, any window size above 0px, do this.

What you need instead is to use "max-width: 500px" for example. This will make the css inside the @media query run below 500px. So by default, make your normal desktop view then use @media screen and (max-width: 500px){} for the mobile table.

```
/* Force table to not be like tables anymore */ 
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
  table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
      display: block; 
  }
}
```

Use what ever screen width you prefer and need however. I'm just using 500px for a good example. Test out what window width you should use by using chromes "inspect element". It will give a handy little box telling you the current window width. Play about and use this to find where you want the display: block to happen.

Remember max-width: ***px means anything below ***px and min-width: ***px is anything above ***px.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your `@media` to only apply at widths where you need it. Examples:

```
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {...}
/* or just */
@media (max-width: 767px) {...}
```

This way it won't apply on any device that has a width larger than `767px`.